# Changing the values like a switch-case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the value of "a" like a switch-case. There are only two values for "a" which is either 0 or 18. Let's take 18 as the intial value, when the length of the name is less than or equal to 5 at first name "Devin", the value is "a" is 18 first, and when the length is greater than 5, the value has to switch to 0 and stay 0 till the next length name greater than 5 doesn't show up. The output should be 18,0,0,0,18,0. The program should flip the values only when the name with length greater than 5 appears.

This is what I tried

```
names = ["Devin","Ashish","Rachi","David","Dohyun","Seonhwa"]
for i in range(len(names)):
    #print(len(names[i]))

    if len(names[i])<=5:
        a =18
    else:
        a=0

    print(a)
```

Comment: This seems fine; where is your problem?

Comment: Minor improvement is to iterate directly over the names: `for name in names:` and then later `if len(name) <= 5:`, instead of using `range` and an intermediate variable `i`.

Comment: `[18 if len(name) <= 5 else 0 for name in names]` ?

Comment: Either your wording of your problem is wrong ("stay 0 till the next length name greater than 6 doesn't show up" is somewhat confusing), or your expectations are incorrect: I wouldn't expect 18 0 0 0 18 0.

Comment: @ChatterOne That's one-lining the for-loop, but doesn't otherwise solve the OPs problem.

Comment: @00 That's because OP didn't state any actual problem, and that's why it's a comment and not an answer

Comment: Your last sentence, "The program should flip the values only when the name with length greater than 5 appears", is in direct contrast to the previous sentences. Should we assume *only* the last sentence as the actual problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["Devin", "Ashish", "Rachi", "David", "Dohyun", "Seonhwa"]
# Pick a start value based on the first name
a = 18 if len(names[0]) <= 5 else 0
print(a)

for name in names[1:]:
    if len(name) > 5:
        a = 0 if a == 18 else 18
    print(a)
```